# Using Powershell to create a Team, channels and creating files

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to create a Team, add channels and then create some folders using Powershell. I have placed the code below (i have commented out the adding of users as that is producing another issue at the moment).

```
#Setup named parameters
param ($TeamName, $TeamDescription, $headteacheremail, $hrcontactemail)

#Sign in to Microsoft Teams with mfa.

Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AccountId user@domain.com


Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName user@domain.com


$team = New-Team -MailNickname $TeamName -displayname $TeamName -Visibility "private"
Write-Host "Team Created: $TeamName"
Write-Host "Team GUID: $team.GroupID"


New-TeamChannel -GroupId $team.GroupId -DisplayName "2021 - 2022 Academic Year"
New-TeamChannel -GroupId $team.GroupId -DisplayName "Induction"
New-TeamChannel -GroupId $team.GroupId -DisplayName "Probation (Support Staff Only)"
New-TeamChannel -GroupId $team.GroupId -DisplayName "Employee Documents" -MembershipType "private"
Write-Host "Channels Created"

#Add the headteacher to the team as a owner
Add-TeamUser -GroupId $team.GroupId -Role Owner -User $headteacheremail
#Add the hr contact to the team as a owner
Add-TeamUser -GroupId $team.GroupId -Role Owner -User $hrcontactemail
Write-Host "Users added to channels"

Write-Host "Sleeping for 10 seconds"
#Give time for MS servers to create the team and channels before trying to interact with them. 10 seconds
Start-Sleep -s 10


#Add-TeamChannelUser -GroupId $team.GroupId -DisplayName "Employee Documents" -User $headteacheremail
#Add-TeamChannelUser -GroupId $team.GroupId -DisplayName "Employee Documents" -User $hrcontactemail
#Write-Host "Users added to channels"

$SiteURL = Get-UnifiedGroup -Identity $TeamName | Select -ExpandProperty SharePointSiteURL

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin

Add-PnPFolder -Name "Bench marking documents" -Folder "Shared Documents/2021 - 2022 Academic Year"
Add-PnPFolder -Name "Career Development Plan - current" -Folder "Shared Documents/2021 - 2022 Academic Year"
Add-PnPFolder -Name "Flick Training Certificates" -Folder "Shared Documents/2021 - 2022 Academic Year"
Add-PnPFolder -Name "Professional Growth Plan - current" -Folder "Shared Documents/2021 - 2022 Academic Year"

Add-PnPFolder -Name "Flick Induction Training Certificate" -Folder "Shared Documents/Induction"
Add-PnPFolder -Name "Induction Policies" -Folder "Shared Documents/Induction"

Add-PnPFolder -Name "3 Month Review" -Folder "Shared Documents/Induction"
Add-PnPFolder -Name "6 Month Review" -Folder "Shared Documents/Induction"
```

The Team is created, channels and users added but when it comes to adding the Folders i get the following error.

```
Connect-PnPOnline : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Url' because it is null.
```

If i run the command on its own with a Team name, it does return the sharepoint URL ok.

I'm not sure what is going on here.

Comment: What if you do `$SiteURL = $team | Get-UnifiedGroup | Select -ExpandProperty SharePointSiteURL` ?

Comment: with that i get "The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input."

Comment: Hmmm. `-Identity` **does** take pipeline input according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-unifiedgroup?view=exchange-ps)..

Answer (score 0):

Strange but i changed it back to the below and its now working. Not sure why or how.

```
$SiteURL = Get-UnifiedGroup -Identity $TeamName | Select -ExpandProperty SharePointSiteURL
```

Now i have just the roadblock that it seems Microsoft do not automatically create the sharepoint folders for individual channels and only appear when opening the respective files section in Teams. Means i can't create folders on Team creation :(

Comment: Back to not working again :( Saying URL is null

Comment: Hi, If you are adding team name manually.. are the folders getting created ?

Comment: @Prithvi-MSFT They do when you open the files tab. I'm testing to see if i can create a channel folder and if it links ok.

Having said that, New-Team has suddendly stopped returning the GroupID. It is just blank.

Experiance of use this module has been woeful so far, it is hit and miss if things work or now.

Comment: Hi @Nathan, So the current issue you are facing is with retrieving group id or creating folders inside channels ?

Comment: @Prithvi-MSFT As of the 2.5 version of the Microsoft Teams module.... Both. New-Team isn't returning the GroupID as before and the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/new-team?view=teams-ps (Example 3) is incorrect.

Comment: Hi @Nathan, We tried it at our end and faced the same issue for getting group id. Seems like a bug

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably resurrecting an old question here, but in case anyone is looking for a solution to the "Roadblock" that OP mentioned.
If you create the channel using graph API, you can then send an "Invoke-RestMethod" to 'initialise' the folder on the SPO site.

You will need to create an app registration and set the headers as per many other guides, then you can use below to create channels and the folders:

```
    function New-TeamChannel {
        Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$TeamID,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$ChannelName
        )
        # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
        $CreateChannelURL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/$TeamID/channels"
        $CreateChannelBody = '{
            "displayName": "'+$ChannelName+'",
            "description": "'+$ChannelName+'",
            "membershipType": "standard"
        }'
        try {
            $channelCreated = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $CreateChannelURL -Method Post -body $CreateChannelBody -Headers $M365headerParams_MSG -ContentType Application/JSON
            write-host "Channel created:" $channelCreated.displayName -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Cyan
            #need to send another call in order to initialise the folder structure in SPO
            $initialiseFolderURL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/$TeamID/channels/"+$channelcreated.id+"/filesfolder"
            $initialisefolder = $null
            $initialisefolder = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $initialiseFolderURL -Method Get -Headers $M365headerParams_MSG 
            if ($initialisefolder) {write-host "Channel initialised in SPO" -ForegroundColor Yellow}
        }
        catch {
            write-host "Error creating channel named $ChannelName" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
```

This can be called in a foreach loop to create many, you just have to provide the arguments each time. "$newteam" is the GUID of the team just created.

```
foreach ($ChannelName in $listofchannels) {
        New-TeamChannel -TeamID $newTeam -ChannelName $channelName
    }
```